# How to create a scrolling background with libGDX

Tags: java, background, libgdx

I'm trying to find a better way to create a scrolling background in android studio for a game I am making. I could just load the image twice and have them scroll side by side, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it. The background needs to be moving at a constant rate, as the character never moves from the center of the screen. The movement of the background is completely independent from everything else.

Comment: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way than

> I could just load the image twice and have them scroll side by side

until they invented.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842432/7113890) there is an example code.